# How to disallow system calls while running a program in a sandbox environment?

Tags: c++, security, fork, sandbox

I was checking out codepad.org and a while(1) fork gave the following output.

Disallowed system call: SYS_fork

Check this link for exact details. http://codepad.org/rNR9mMVv

Googling more, I got to to know that they also disable system call using sockets.

Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall

Can anyone tell me how one can disable certain system calls before running the program in a sandboxed environment?

Comment: I think this would be a kernel level issue rather than specific to C++ or any other native binaries.  Unless there's a C++ interpreter out there somewhere that can run the code in a non-native environment?

Answer (score 1):

By replacing runtime libraries with mocks that have empty stubs or exception throwers instead of real functions?

Comment: But won't that disable the actual functionality of these functions. For example, if I replace the runtime time libraries of fork() and if I want to fork in my code, but disable fork in the code submitted by others, will this method still work? If yes, then please let me know how.. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just postulating, I guess that for the proper implementation, you'll have to create some kind of sandbox environment, so you'll have your runtimes duplicated - one real and one as a shadow.

Comment: Does not work. Somebody who gets in can use inline assembly to directly access the syscall gateway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to pay the performance penalty, ptrace() can be used for this. There's another way I cannot seem to find right now.

Answer (score 0):

System calls work by injecting the function into the process by the operating system. If, however, you wrote a custom loader for your favourite executable format, you would have the power to link it against your own. You could also binary alter the executable, if the format allows for it, to pull those functions from a separate dynamic library, provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was researching the same stuff, so here is my suggestion - use [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page). The [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) project, has some [nice stuff](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?full=1) about SELinux. Have a look at the [SELinux Policy Types](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?full=1#book_part2_chap4) (4.b), and the **targeted** policy in particular. I'm not sure about [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/), but the similar [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) uses Gentoo, so perhaps SELinux should be the easiest way to go.